# Edit suggestion rejected and approved at the same time

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

Some hours ago I have [fixed multiple issues a post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/24119). This edit was *rejected* by the community user without any reason, a [long standing bug on our network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153403/add-a-reject-reason-when-the-community-user-rejects-an-edit).

Strange enough, but now I see my edit was *approved* too – but [its “author” is Alex](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/49899/2). I don’t care whose name shows up in the edit history as long as the post was actually improved.

But I would like to know what happened here. Why was my suggestion rejected *and* approved? Why are the names mangled, and why is there still no reject reason visible?

Comment: Perhaps you can consider reading my answer yet again: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/a/2433/29140

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What seems to have happened is that the suggested edit was looked at - the reviewer decided to improve it but also unselected the checkbox for "this edit was helpful", causing the suggested edit to be rejected, but also for your changes to be incorporated into his edit.

Comment: I just wish he had actually improved it. He reversed the necessary fix for `chidren's`. :/

Comment: @toscho - Not arguing here. As since he took most of your edits, he shouldn't have unchecked that checkbox.