# How long are our edit suggestions valid for?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I had recently suggested an [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76559) for a post ([Inbox older emails are swept. How can I recover them?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95931/inbox-older-emails-are-swept-how-can-i-recover-them))

Although moderator [Sathya♦](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/310/sathya) later made an [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/95931/2) to the same post (without approving mine) my (already approved by [Al E.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/354/al-e)) edit was also approved by [jonsca♦](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/11175/jonsca)  and was finally accepted and published. (Probably a mix-up similar to [this](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2488/edit-suggestion-rejected-and-approved-at-the-same-time) question)
The whole process for my suggestion to be approved took some 22 hours.

I (regardless of who, when and how) wonder.
**Is there a time limit after which suggested edits -if not approved- get deleted automatically or do they live forever in the deep web?**

The closest I got to an answer was at this post: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

> **Where do suggested edits go?**
>
> Suggested edits are held in a peer review queue of a fixed size. If
>   the queue fills up, no more edit suggestions will be allowed until the
>   queue has some empty space.

In the given answer where can this queue be found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no time limit. Suggested edits do not age away like votes to close. They'll wait for someone to act on them or for someone to make an edit that invalidates the suggestion.

See: [this answer to a similar question on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263749/21960)

An [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/350400/maxium-minutes-of-suggested-edit-before-final#resultSets) shows that suggested edits here are processed, on average, in 2 hours, with the maximum ever being 280 hours (11 ⅔ days).

The [Suggested Edits queue](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) is one of the [review queues](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review) and for Web Apps lives at: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits

You gain access to this queue at the same time you gain the "[edit everywhere](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)" privilege, which is 2,000 reputation.

Comment: Tag wiki suggested edits are an entirely different beast.

Comment: Sure, but the question was asking about posts (and the SEDE query only looks at posts).